# Highcharts passing time.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get the x-axis to display the day on which the  data was pulled.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    day: '%e' 
},
```

So far I've tried.

1.

```
data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 11),0.12],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 10),-1.54],[Date.UTC(2013, 5,   9),-1.76],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 8),-3.94],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 7),-3.52],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 6),-2.35],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 5),-3.29],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 4),-3.21],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3),-1.37],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 2),-1.87],[Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1),-1.77],[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 30),-1.89],[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 29),-1.69],[Date.UTC(2013, 4, 28),-1.63]]
```

2.

```
data: [[1368331081,0.12],[1368244681,-1.54],[1368158281,-1.76],[1368071881,-3.94],[1367985481,-3.52],[1367899081,-2.35],[1367812681,-3.29],[1367726281,-3.21],[1367639881,-1.37],[1367553481,-1.87],[1367467081,-1.77],[1367380681,-1.89],[1367294281,-1.69],[1367207881,-1.63]]
```

Both error out.   Honestly I'm confused with this. What is the easy way to pass the timestamp for the xaxis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { day: '%e'}
}
```

Working jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tz8ea/

Comment: Thanks much mike. I knew it was probably close.